# How to deny trace requests via htaccess?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, http-method

I want to disable the trace and track methods via htaccess.

With following snippet in my htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
```

I get the following answers

```
url -v -X TRACK obscuredurl* Adding handle: conn: 0x7f8c43004400
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7f8c43004400) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to obscuredurl port 80 (#0)
*   Trying xx.xx.xxx.xx...
* Connected to obscuredurl (xx.xx.xxx.xx) port 80 (#0)
> TRACK / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: obscuredurl
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
< Date: Tue, 14 Jan 2014 09:53:45 GMT
* Server Apache is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache
< Allow: TRACE
< Content-Length: 296
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
<
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The requested method TRACK is not allowed for the URL /.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache Server at obscuredurl Port 80</address>
</body></html>
* Closing connection 0
```

And

```
curl -v -X TRACE obscuredurl
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7ff339004400
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7ff339004400) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to obscuredurl port 80 (#0)
*   Trying xx.xx.xxx.xx...
* Connected to obscuredurl (xx.xx.xxx.xx) port 80 (#0)
> TRACE / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: obscuredurl
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 14 Jan 2014 09:55:15 GMT
* Server Apache is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache
< Connection: close
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: message/http
<
TRACE / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
Host: obscuredurl
Accept: */*

* Closing connection 0
```

So it seems to work with TRACK but not with trace. Two separated conditions work either.

How can I debug it?

Thanks

Comment: To answer the actual question: debug rewrite rules by enabling `RewriteLog` and raising the log level. You could also just put `TraceEnable off` in the global `httpd.conf`.

Comment: [This topic implies your approach should work fine](http://superuser.com/q/655446).

Comment: I cant modify the httpd.conf on this server. It is not mine. Is it possible that 'traceEnable On' in httpd.conf overrules the htaccess?

Comment: @noeden, I would suggest to setup a server which you can debug on. A local development server for example.

Answer (score 1):

Difference is in Apache handling of `TRACE` and `TRACK` request methods. As you noticed `TRACK` request is duly handled by `mod_rewrite` rule in Apache but `TRACE` is handled by Apache at much higher level **even before reading your .htacess** You can verify that by putting some garbage text in `.htaccess` and then invoking `TRACE` request to get a proper response instead of expected `500 (Internal Server Error)`.

You may need to request your server admin to add this in Apache server config:

```
TraceEnable Off
```

to switch off `TRACE`.